# Use an encrypted variable in Travis as the value of a secure key?

Tags: travis-ci

I've tried a variety of solutions and I can't find something that works.  My problem is that I want to be able to put a deployment key (what GitHub calls a *personal authorization token* or *personal OAuth token*) into an encrypted variable in my Travis settings for the repository so that the configuration file never has to change.  For example, I'd like to do this:

`deploy:
    api_key:
        secure: $DEPLOYMENT_KEY`

I could now checkin code that doesn't need to be changed in order to be deployed.  If multiple people were to fork my repository, they could simply add their own Travis variable and not touch the code at all.

However, I've been unsuccessful in getting this to work.  What sequence would accomplish this, if it's possible at all?

## Solution

I accepted the answer below that put me on the right track, although the actual text that I needed in my configuration file wasn't shown.  I've put it here:

`deploy:
    api_key: $DEPLOYMENT_KEY`

I had a "eureka!" moment and realized that any subway of 'secure:' could be replaced with an actual *unencrypted* value, which is what Travis inserts when you substitute an *encrypted* variable.  (It does the decryption and puts the result into the variable, which is then substituted into the `api_key` by the dollar sign.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot write:

```
deploy:
  api_key:
    secure: $DEPLOYMENT_KEY
```

Decryption happens in an early stage of Travis CI build processing; the encrypted value will be passed on to the app which compiles the bash script to build. Since the part that is responsible for decrypting secrets doesn't know anything about `$DEPLOYMENT_KEY`, this configuration will fail.

To achieve what you are after, you can use the repository settings to define secrets. See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings.

Comment: Ah, I think I understand!  Eureka! ;)  Please check the edit I made to your answer and see if I got it right, please?  (Can't do proper formatting in a comment.)  I'll test this and come back to select this answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Your "edit" is a response to my answer, so it's not appropriate as such.

Comment: Oh.  I wanted it to be easy for others to see what the actual solution was, since your answer quoted what _didn't_ work.  And I tried putting it here but the formatting didn't work.  I'll go back and edit my question, instead.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thus, I understand that:

- either, you put an awful long encrypted key in your `.travis.yml`
- or, you put an unencrypted key in a Travis environment variable, so that if any developer of the GitHub project can add in `.travis.yml` something like:

  `echo "${API_TOKEN:0:1}%POISON%${API_TOKEN:1}"`

  he can get your private API_TOKEN secret by reading travis logs (even if your variable is not set as `DISPLAY VALUE IN BUILD LOG` since this hack disrupts the usual `[secure]` replacement in logs)

Reminder: since GitHub API_TOKEN is not restricted by repository, that *bad guy* can do anything with all your repositories (write access and read access to your private repo).

NB: I found this [blog post](https://blog.algolia.com/travis-encrypted-variables-external-contributions/) with a more safe solution (but not perfect) which requires an external server to serve temporary API_TOKEN.

Is there any other solution ?